# Options for using C++11 <regex> with a circa 2013 compiler

Tags: regex, c++11

Is there any full/correct implementation available (**right now**) for C++11 regex?

Note on Compiler support vs. Library support:

**Compiler Support** = compiler recognizes any new syntax added to the language for the feature in question.  Code utilizing the new feature added to your program will compile.

**Library Support** = library updated to actually implement the feature. Code added to your program and linked to the library will work.

*Edit: I've updated this summary with new information and moved it into an answer below.

Comment: There has been a lot of work recently to add `<regex>` support to libstdc++. At least part of the regex algorithms should be usable in GCC 4.9.

Comment: For MSVC you have msdn page with what syntax is supported by which version of visual http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982727%28v=vs.120%29.aspx

Comment: Isn't Clang supposed to be C++11 fully compatible by now? [Clang status](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html)

Comment: @RedX Clang the compiler, yes. libc++ the library, also yes. In both cases, of course, there may be bugs. However, when you use Clang with a different standard library, you are of course limited to what that library supports, so if you use a current libstdc++, you don't have regex.

Comment: there is "regex.h" that's super old and works for everything essentially. I was using <regex> but realized my build didn't C++11 so I essentially switched to "regex.h" (a little bit more complicated) and it worked. It's posix/windows also.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Per stack exchange policy about it being ok to answer your own question I am updating 
the summary part of the question with new info and moving it into this answer.

**GCC:**    Does not provide a working `regex` until GCC 4.9.0

**Clang:**  Compiles regex

**Standard Library:**

- regex only supported by **libstdc++** since GCC 4.9.0 (GNU's standard lib)
- regex is supported by **libc++** (LLVM's standard lib)
- **libc++** fully verified on **Mac OS**
- **libc++** can be built from source for other platforms.
- (I built and verified some of regex on **Linux**)

**MSVC:**   Regex works since **MSVC 2010** (Per answer from @Laurent and associated up votes)

**Boost:** 
C++11 regex is "based on" or "modeled after" Boost. 
I take that to mean not exactly the same. 
If there is a definitive list of differences please comment with a link.

Comment: This list will be far more insightful than my answer, don't worry about answering your own question. +1

Comment: The GCC/Clang compiler part of this answer is irrelevant really, any version of GCC or Clang since about 2011 supports all the necessary language features for `<regex>`, it's only a question of whether it's provided in the standard library you use with the compiler.

Answer (score 5):

I've used the `<regex>` module since MSVC 2010 and it worked perfectly for my need (using the doc from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/)).

So if you intend to develop on a Windows environment, I would recommend opting for MSVC 2010 or 2012. It works out of the box !

Answer (score 1):

Clang is C++11 feature complete. You can check which feature is available in which version here: [Clang C++11 features](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html)

Comment: Don't confuse language feature support in a compiler with library feature support in a library.