# g++ regex header file

Tags: c++, regex, macos

I have been working in c++ for a while and something came up. I tried to include ***regex*** header. But compiler won't find the header file.

However, when I try to compile same file using clang++, It compiles and works great.

Sample code I tried was from [here](http://solarianprogrammer.com/2011/10/12/cpp-11-regex-tutorial/)

Comment: Is it giving you an error like this `#error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.` by any chance?

Comment: error I get is  'error: regex: No such file or directory' and rest for all other component from regex used.

also when I try 'g++ -std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++' I get error message 
'cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++0x"
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-stdlib=libc++"'

Comment: also my g++ version is 

i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2

Comment: I suspect this answers your question, sadly. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14229045

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the C++ library the compiler uses. E.g. for GCC 4.9 `regex` is now implemented. [Options for using C++11  today](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18645297/172695) summarizes this quite well.